# Display a Modal Popup window

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here I am trying to display a modal popup window by using button click event.

This is Modal popup division

```
<div id="myModalPopup" class="modal fade" role="dialog" data-keyboard="false">//Modal popup
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header" style="background-color: orangered; border-top-left-radius: 4px; border-top-right-radius: 4px;">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Company Details</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" class="tab-pane">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblNmeComp" Text="Name of Company" AssociatedControlID="txtNmeComp" CssClass="control-label" />
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtNmeComp" CssClass="form-control" />
                            <br />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblAdrComp" Text="Address of Company" AssociatedControlID="txtAdrComp" CssClass="control-label" />
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtAdrComp" CssClass="form-control" />
                            <br />
                        </div>
```

This is My button code

```
<button id="AddMore_Button" class="btn btn-primary" data-target="myModalPopup">Add More</button> //button for Add more
```

This is My Jquery.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

 // Attach Button click event listener 
    $("#AddMore_Button").click(function () {
      $('#myModal').modal('show');
 // alert('a');
});
});
    </script>
```

Here when I click button it's not displaying anything, then refreshing and going to first screen. If I put alert() it fires and after pressing OK same thing happening.

Comment: show us the html also

Comment: Can you please put the jsfiddle link what have you done yet?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/AUyTH/108/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/AUyTH/109/ here Pramanand has provided right answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to show the modal

```
$('#myModalPopup').modal('show');
```

Comment: If it works! Please mark as answered. So that it will be helpful for others as well, if they required.

Comment: its working. But my issue is it is refreshing to first page. So I kept                                 return false;. so it came perfectely